# Como fazer no HQL uma consulta por ID usando o operador LIKE?

Tags: jpql, hql

Como faço essa consulta em HQL?

```
select * from entidadeQualquer where  id::text like '%12';
```

Já tentei o código abaixo mas não funcionou:

```
select c from entidadeQualquerc  where  c.id like '%12';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem o código da entidade não dá para ter certeza, mas você pode tentar algo assim:

```
String hql = "select c from entidadeQualquer c where CAST(id as text) like :id";
```

E para definir o parâmetro:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", "%12");
List<EntidadeQualquer> lista = query.getResultList()
```

Comment: Funcionou , faltava fazer o CAST!

Answer (score 1):

Pra mim, funcionou assim:

```
String sql = "select t from Tabela t where str(t.id) like :id";
```

parametro:

```
query.setParameter("id", "%" + parteDoIdPassadoComoParametro + "%");
```